# ERROR: Unknown compiler(s): [['ifort'], ['gfortran'], ['flang'], ['pgfortran'], ['g95']] -- What should I do?

Tags: python, pip, fortran

I tried to `pip install -r requirements_versions.txt` , however I keep getting the same error message regarding Fortran compilers. I'm not sure where to install them from as I tried from their website but I might've messed up since it's still not working. All answers are much appreciated!

```
× Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.   │ exit code: 1   ╰─> [37 lines of output]
      + meson setup C:\Users\bagda\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-cyk95ir8\scipy_3e9529a1d9cd407a96011bdcdb5c5cd6 C:\Users\bagda\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-cyk95ir8\scipy_3e9529a1d9cd407a96011bdcdb5c5cd6\.mesonpy-90rqinq2
-Dbuildtype=release -Db_ndebug=if-release -Db_vscrt=md --native-file=C:\Users\bagda\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-cyk95ir8\scipy_3e9529a1d9cd407a96011bdcdb5c5cd6\.mesonpy-90rqinq2\meson-python-native-file.ini
      The Meson build system
      Version: 1.3.0
      Source dir: C:\Users\bagda\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-cyk95ir8\scipy_3e9529a1d9cd407a96011bdcdb5c5cd6
      Build dir: C:\Users\bagda\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-cyk95ir8\scipy_3e9529a1d9cd407a96011bdcdb5c5cd6\.mesonpy-90rqinq2
      Build type: native build
      Project name: SciPy
      Project version: 1.9.3
      Activating VS 17.8.2
      C compiler for the host machine: cl (msvc 19.38.33130 "Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.38.33130 for x64")
      C linker for the host machine: link link 14.38.33130.0
      C++ compiler for the host machine: cl (msvc 19.38.33130 "Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.38.33130 for x64")
      C++ linker for the host machine: link link 14.38.33130.0
      Host machine cpu family: x86_64
      Host machine cpu: x86_64
      Compiler for C supports arguments -Wno-unused-but-set-variable: NO
      Compiler for C supports arguments -Wno-unused-but-set-variable: NO (cached)
      Compiler for C supports arguments -Wno-unused-function: NO
      Compiler for C supports arguments -Wno-conversion: NO
      Compiler for C supports arguments -Wno-misleading-indentation: NO
      Compiler for C supports arguments -Wno-incompatible-pointer-types: NO
      Library m found: NO

      ..\meson.build:57:0: ERROR: Unknown compiler(s): [['ifort'], ['gfortran'], ['flang'], ['pgfortran'], ['g95']]
      The following exception(s) were encountered:
      Running `ifort --version` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
      Running `ifort -V` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
      Running `gfortran --version` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
      Running `gfortran -V` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
      Running `flang --version` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
      Running `flang -V` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
      Running `pgfortran --version` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
      Running `pgfortran -V` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
      Running `g95 --version` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
      Running `g95 -V` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"

      A full log can be found at C:\Users\bagda\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-cyk95ir8\scipy_3e9529a1d9cd407a96011bdcdb5c5cd6\.mesonpy-90rqinq2\meson-logs\meson-log.txt
      [end of output]
```

Comment: IMO you're doing things in the wrong way. Compiling NumPy, SciPy and Torch is quite hard. On w32 it's close to impossible. Instead you should install precompiled wheels. If [this](https://github.com/lllyasviel/Fooocus/blob/main/requirements_versions.txt) is the list of dependencies then you need numpy==1.23.5 and scipy==1.9.3. They provide wheels up to Python 3.11 but not 3.12 ([numpy](https://pypi.org/project/numpy/1.23.5/#files), [scipy](https://pypi.org/project/scipy/1.9.3/#files)).

Comment: So my advice is: stop using Python 3.12, switch to 3.11. Uninstall Python 3.12, install Python 3.11, change `PATH`, and reinstall `pip install -r requirements_versions.txt`.